# Cannot find name 'IProp'. ts(2304) in VS Code with TS 3.3.3 namespace

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, namespaces

I'm trying to create a namespaced interface in a d.ts file to use in a different file using same namespace but my IDE flags the interface in the new file with the message: `Cannot find name 'IProps'. ts(2304)`.

I have Typescript 3.3.333333 installed globally. My VScode IDE status bar displays Typescript 3.3.3.

```
/*
    t.d.ts
*/
import {Map} from 'immutable';
declare namespace Configs {
    export type Power = {
        horse: number,
        torque?: number
    }
    export interface IProps {
        displacement: number,
        options?: Map<string, any>,
        power: Power
    }
}

/*
    index.ts
*/
/// <reference path="./t.d.ts" />
import {Map} from 'immutable';
declare namespace Configs {
    export let props: IProps = { // Error - IDE here flags IProps
        displacement: 3.2,
        options: Map(),
        power: {
            horse: 560
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After happening upon the ‘Modules and Namespaces’ page in the typescript docs, it turns out that the ‘declare’ keyword was not needed for this usage. I removed it from the files and the namespaced properties became available. Neither the es6 export/import nor the triple slashes referencing were required to properly emit and consume those properties. I also reset the —isolateModules flag to its defaults to allow for proper compilation of cross-file namespaces.